# Create Excel with JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have an API who takes any JSON and I want to make a Excel with it. I'm using

> Json.Decode(json)

for convert that JSON in a dynamic object, but I don't know how to access to any key and value created by the decoder.

How can I reference each key and value created?

My code:

**Request model**

```
/// <summary>
/// Request de servicio Excel
/// </summary>
public class GenerarExcelRequest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Lista de elementos
    /// </summary>
    public string NombreArchivo { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// JSON a convertir en Excel
    /// </summary>
    public object Modelo { get; set; }
}
```

**Service**

```
public GenerarExcelResponse GenerarExcel(GenerarExcelRequest request)
{
    using (ExcelPackage exc = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        ExcelWorksheet ex = exc.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Reporte Excel");

        // If the dynamic object != null, convert it

        var modeloDecode = request.Modelo != null ? request.Modelo = Json.Decode(request.Modelo.ToString()) : null;

        // I get every value and key created and make the key header of the Excel
        if (modeloDecode == null)
            return new GenerarExcelResponse() { RutaArchivoExcel = ""};

        //var listaEncabezados = 

        // Load every value in the Excel

        // Return the file path of the new Excel

        string filePath = "C:\\" + request.NombreArchivo;

        byte[] bin = exc.GetAsByteArray();
        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bin);
        return new GenerarExcelResponse()
        {
            RutaArchivoExcel = filePath
        };
     }
 }
```

**JSON Input Example:**

```
{
    "NombreArchivo": "Prueba",
    "Modelo": [
        {
            "id": 24135,
            "nombre": "Ignacio"          
        },
        {
            "id": 28733,
            "nombre": "Francisco"           
        }
    ]
}
```

**Excel Output I want**

Id ---------- Nombre

24135 ------- Ignacio

28733 ------- Francisco

But the next time that someone use this API may send this input:

**JSON Input Example 2:**

```
{
    "NombreArchivo": "Prueba2",
    "Modelo": [
        {
            "id": 25,
            "product": "XXAA2121",          
            "stock": 21
        },
        {
            "id": 23,
            "product": "XXFJJ212"           
            "stock": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

And want to make and Excel like this:

**Excel Output I want**

Id ---------- Product --------- Stock

25 ---------- XXAA2121 -------- 21

23 ---------- XXFJJ212 -------- 4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create excel file using json data using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51419866/how-to-create-excel-file-using-json-data-using-c)

Comment: What I'm trying to do, and I don't know if it possible, is to take any JSON (which I don't know his format) and make a Excel with it. In that question, the output is allways the same, that why I using **object** in the input JSON, and the decoder is differentiating well the keys and values, but I don't know how to access to them with the Json.Decode

Comment: How do you want to expext the input to be formed. I mean an execl sheet is plainly a table and that should on someway be reflected in the input. Please provide example input.

Comment: I feel you need something **dynamic**. I don't have the answer for you but I guess I can show you the way. Here's a example [Exporting DataTable To Excel in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/exporting-datatable-to-excel-in-C-Sharp-using-interop/)

Comment: You can follow two different approaches: or you transform the input JSON into a DataTable or your change the input of the method of the mentioned link above.

Comment: Are you saying the structure will be different or just the names of the fields?

Comment: The structure of the input may be different.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you want, if this should work regardless of the structure of the doc, but something like this might do what you need to get it into a flat list.  From there, its a trivial matter to put it into excel.  This is a working example from Linqpad once you add Json.NET as a nuget package.

```
void Main()
{
    var jsonFoo = @"{
    ""NombreArchivo"": ""Prueba"",

    ""Modelo"": [
        {
            ""id"": 24135,
            ""nombre"": ""Ignacio""          
        },
        {
    ""id"": 28733,
            ""nombre"": ""Francisco""

        }
    ]
}";
    
var foo = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonFoo);
foo.Dump();
var dict = new List<Tuple<string,string>>();
ConvertJsonToDictionary(foo, dict);
dict.Dump();
}
// Define other methods and classes here

public void ConvertJsonToDictionary(JToken foo, List<Tuple<string,string>> dict)
{
    switch(foo.Type)
    {
        case JTokenType.Object:
            foreach (var item in (JObject)foo)
            {
                dict.Add(new Tuple<string,string>(item.Key, item.Value.ToString()));
                if (item.Value.GetType() == typeof(JArray))
                {
                    ConvertJsonToDictionary(item.Value, dict);
                }
            }
            break;
        case JTokenType.Array:
            foreach(var item in (JArray)foo)
            {
                ConvertJsonToDictionary(item, dict);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a trouble with this code. First, in the line **var foo = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonFoo);** I use like this **var foo = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(request.Modelo.ToString());**, but an exception throw saying **"Cannot convert from 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.'"** And second, the method Dump don't exist on a JObect. Any suggestion?

Comment: Dump is an extension method that is part of the free Linqpad tool I mentioned.  That is just to demonstrate the raw contents of the dictionary and output it to the screen.  You shouldn't use Dump in your working application.  As for your conversion issues, that may be an issue with the version of Newtonsoft that you are using.  I am using the latest which I believe is 12.0.3.  If you are unable to get Linqpad working, here is a working example in dotnetfiddle.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/SUHTDT